# Python3 - Migrating to Pydantic v2 with RootModel

Tags: python, python-3.x, pydantic

I'm trying to migrate my repo to  use pydantic v2, but I'm having some issues with the model validation.

- The `TestModelv1` was my previous implementation, and it works fine (although I'm not sure if it's the best way to do it).
- The `TestModelv2` is my new implementation, but it's not validating properly.
- The code should be working as is.

```py
from typing import Any

import pandas as pd
from pydantic.v1 import BaseModel, validator
from pydantic import RootModel, model_validator


class TestModelv1(BaseModel):
    """Pydantic v1"""

    __root__: pd.DataFrame

    @validator("__root__", pre=True)
    def convert_data(cls, v: dict[Any, Any]) -> pd.DataFrame:
        columns: list[str] = ["time", "a", "b", "c"]

        # Units conversions
        df: pd.DataFrame = pd.DataFrame(v, columns=columns, index=[0])
        df[["a", "b", "c"]] = df[["a", "b", "c"]].astype(float)

        df["time"] = pd.to_datetime(df["time"], unit="ms")

        return df

    class Config:
        arbitrary_types_allowed = True


class TestModelv2(RootModel[Any]):
    """Pydantic v2"""

    root: pd.DataFrame

    @model_validator(mode="before")
    def convert_data(cls, v: dict[Any, Any]) -> pd.DataFrame:
        columns: list[str] = ["a", "b", "c"]

        # Units conversions
        df: pd.DataFrame = pd.DataFrame(v, columns=columns)
        df[["a", "b", "c"]] = df[["a", "b", "c"]].astype(float)

        df["time"] = pd.to_datetime(df["time"], unit="ms")

        return df

    class Config:
        arbitrary_types_allowed = True


def main() -> None:
    response: str = '{"time": 1690886519000, "a": "1", "b": "2", "c": "3"}'

    test_v1: TestModelv1 = TestModelv1.parse_raw(response)
    print(test_v1.__root__)

    # Model validation error of test_v2 -------------v
    # pydantic_core._pydantic_core.ValidationError: 1 validation error for TestModelv2
    # Value error, DataFrame constructor not properly called!
    # [type=value_error, input_value='{"time": 1690886519000,"...1", "b": "2", "c": "3"}', input_type=str]
    test_v2: TestModelv2 = TestModelv2.model_validate(response)
    print(test_v2.root)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I'm struggling to understand how to use the RootModel and model_validator properly.
Any suggestions? Thanks!

I was trying to migrate my code to pydantic v2 with RootModels but couldn't reprocude the functionalities I had with pydantic v1

Answer (score 3):

Turns out I was using the wrong `model_validate` instead of `model_validate_json`:

```py
from typing import Any

import pandas as pd
from pydantic.v1 import BaseModel, validator as validator_v1
from pydantic import RootModel, validator as validator_v2


class TestModelv1(BaseModel):
    """Pydantic v1"""

    __root__: pd.DataFrame

    @validator_v1("__root__", pre=True)
    def convert_data(cls, v: dict[Any, Any]) -> pd.DataFrame:
        columns: list[str] = ["time", "a", "b", "c"]

        # Units conversions
        df: pd.DataFrame = pd.DataFrame(v, columns=columns, index=[0])
        df[["a", "b", "c"]] = df[["a", "b", "c"]].astype(float)

        df["time"] = pd.to_datetime(df["time"], unit="ms")

        return df

    class Config:
        arbitrary_types_allowed = True


class TestModelv2(RootModel[Any]):
    """Pydantic v2"""

    root: pd.DataFrame

    @validator_v2("root", pre=True)
    def convert_data(cls, v: dict[Any, Any]) -> pd.DataFrame:
        columns: list[str] = ["time", "a", "b", "c"]

        # Units conversions
        df: pd.DataFrame = pd.DataFrame(v, columns=columns, index=[0])
        df[["a", "b", "c"]] = df[["a", "b", "c"]].astype(float)

        df["time"] = pd.to_datetime(df["time"], unit="ms")

        return df

    class Config:
        arbitrary_types_allowed = True


def main() -> None:
    response: str = '{"time": 1690886519000, "a": "1", "b": "2", "c": "3"}'

    test_v1: TestModelv1 = TestModelv1.parse_raw(response)
    print(test_v1.__root__)

    test_v2: TestModelv2 = TestModelv2.model_validate_json(response)
    print(test_v2.root)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```